# Expressing an abelian group as a sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abelian-groups

> Find an isomorphic direct product of cyclic groups, where $V$ is an abelian group generated by $x,y,z$ and subject to relations:
>   $$3x + 2y + 8z = 0,\qquad 2x + 4z = 0.$$

The answer is $C_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$

But I don't know how to get the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting twice the second equation from the first you get $-x+2y=0$. So $x$ is superfluous. You're left with $\langle y,z : 4y+4z=0 \rangle$ which is the same as $\langle y,t : 4t=0 \rangle$, for $t=y+z$. This is $C_4 \times C_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a homomorphism from the free abelian group of rank $3$, generated by $x$, $y$, and $z$, onto $V$, with kernel given by the equations: $3x+2y+8z=0$, $2x+4z=0$. Finding the kernel is the same as finding the *integral* kernel of the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 2 & 8\\
2 & 0 & 4
\end{array}\right)$$
which can be found using Gaussian elimination or Smith Normal form. 
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 2& 8\\
2 & 0 & 4
\end{array}\right) &\to \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 4\\
2 & 0 & 4
\end{array}\right) &&\to \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 4\\
0 & -4 & -4
\end{array}\right)\\
&\to\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2&  4\\
0 & 4 & 4
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
This tells you that $x+2y+4z =0$ and $4y+4z=0$. This in turn says that you can get $x$ from $y$ and $z$, that $y+z$ has order $4$, So you can generate the group with $y+z$ and $z$, subject only to the condition that $y+z$ has order $4$. This gives you the cyclic summand of order $4$ (for $\langle y+z\rangle$), and an infinite cyclic group (for $z$).